# Bluetooth keyboard stopped working after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

I've upgraded to OS X Yosemite and now my wireless bluetooth keyboard is not connecting anymore.  I have a bluetooth Belkin 10 keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried the standard - reboot bluetooth & computer, change batteries etc?

Comment: I did, changed batteries, removed it from the Bluetooth listing and have been trying to re add to the bluetooth devices and it keeps telling me connection failed.

Comment: Ive tried both replies to no avail, the 10Key belkin connects without issue and i have 2 apple keyboards, tried both and neither is connecting, it finds them, it just wont allow them to connect

Comment: this did the trick:  http://davemeehan.com/technology/how-to-reset-an-apple-wireless-bluetooth-keyboard-mouse-or-trackpad

Answer (score 1):

I seem  to have fixed this now.

1. I went into Bluetooth prefs and removed the mouse and Keyboard.
2. I removed to batteries from both.
3. Rebooted.
4. Went to System Preferences → Mouse
5. Put batteries back into mouse, re-paired **mouse only**
6. Rebooted.
7. Went to System Preferences → Keyboard → Connect Bluetooth Keyboard.
8. Re-paired keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
So I changed the batteries on the keyboard, turned the keyboard **ON** and then restarted the computer. It connected then.

I found that if the computer is dotted up and not the keyboard it won't connect. Hope this works.

Answer (score -2):

[Dave Meehan's technique](http://davemeehan.com/technology/how-to-reset-an-apple-wireless-bluetooth-keyboard-mouse-or-trackpad) worked for me:

1. Switch off the keyboard by holding down the power button for at least 3 seconds
2. Click the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar
3. Click on “Set Up Bluetooth Device” or “Open Bluetooth Preferences”
4. urn on the keyboard by holding down the power button, *but do not let go of the power button*. It must be kept held down through the entire process.
5. The Setup Assistant will find the keyboard, so click the name of the keyboard, and then click on “Continue”. Make sure you are still holding the power button down.
6. You will be prompted for the Pairing Code. You can now release the power button, type the pairing code on the keyboard and then press return. There will be a slight delay whilst the pairing completes (a few seconds)
7. The keyboard will now be Paired.

So just to clarify, the trick is to continually *hold down the power button*.